# simple animation with javascript interval

Tags: javascript

I'm set up a simple animation with set Interval. 
But I wanted to do an animation where it moves to a target position over time. 
I used to this back in the flash days and have forgotten the process. 
It remember using something like

```
property = (target - property)/speed;
```

But having a problem setting that up with the below setup.
I understand there is a 100 ways to do this and even using css but I just want to know how I could implement with that I have now. I just want that ease over time to happen with setInterval.

```
var sq = document.querySelector('.square');
button = document.querySelector('button');

var interval, toggle = 0, pos=0;
var targetX = 100;
var startX = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", (event) =>{
      toggle += 1;
      toggle = toggle % 2;

      if( toggle > 0){
          interval = setInterval(animate, 5);
        }else{
          clearInterval(interval);
      }

    });

    function animate(){
       //pos++
       //sq.style.left = pos + 'px';
         sq.style.left = (targetX - sq.style.left) / speed
    }
```

Comment: fyi ... `toggle += 1;
      toggle = toggle % 2;` === `toggle = 1 - toggle` ... but `toggle = !toggle` and `if (toggle) ...` makes even more sense

Comment: `having a problem setting that up with the below setup` - what's the problem? the code seems valid enough

Comment: some `html` and `css` will make it a little bit easier to find out the problem.

Comment: Sorry @ericB i misread your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setInterval()` isn't the best choice for animations since it cannot sync to monitor updates. A better choice, and highly recommended, is `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Right now the code uses an interval of 5ms which is way too low. The shortest frame update happens at 16.7ms (at 60Hz screens) so there is much overhead here.

I would also suggest using linear interpolation (AKA lerp) to do the animation, and time duration to define speed. Using interpolation allows you to further feed the `t` into an easing function.

### Example

- `t` is calculated based on start-time, current time and duration
- `t`, now normalized to [0, 1] is fed to lerp function to obtain new position
- translateX is used to move div to allow subpixeled animation. Final position can still be set by removing translation and a fixed position for `left`.

```js
var reqId,                                      // request ID so we can cancel anim.
    startTime = 0,
    source = 0,
    target = 300, 
    duration = 1000,                            // duration in ms
    sq = document.querySelector("div");
    
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  startTime = 0;                                // reset time for t
  cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);                  // abort existing animation if any
  reqId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);          // start new with time argument
  
  function loop(time) {
    if (!startTime) startTime = time;           // set start time if not set already
    t = (time - startTime) / duration;          // calc t
    
    var x = lerp(source, target, t);            // lerp between source and target position
    sq.style.transform = "translateX("+x+"px)"; // use transform to allow sub-pixeling
    
    if (t < 1) requestAnimationFrame(loop);     // loop until t=1
    // else { here you can remove transform and set final position ie. using left}
  }
  
  // basic linear interpolation
  function lerp(v1, v2, t) {return v1 + (v2-v1) * t}
};
```

```css
div {position:absolute; left:0; top:40px; width:100px;height:100px;background:#c33}
```

```html
<button>Animate</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Can you use this without using lerp and just x = (target - x)/speed;

Comment: @ericb sure, lerp just makes it easy to bind the movement to time for timing purposes, but you can use a fixed increment based on dist/speed as well. Instead of checking t, just check if current distance has reached target length (I would recommend you too look into using vectors in that case if you're not already familiar with them).